# codeigniter 4 url links to outside webpages, how is that done with a controller?

Tags: redirect, codeigniter-4

```
 How do you use a controller to link to an outside website
```

in codeigniter 4? I would prefer to use a controller named Links
with links to outside webpages, no success period. In theory
i could setup named routes, assign website addresses in functions. No clear examples are available, i did find a CI3 method to do so and it failed. Codeigniter 4 url addressing is very difficult, please help!

Comment: Attempted to set named routes with Controller/function calls that would let me go out of the site to say Google.com, url helper call triggered errors, complaints of reverse routing error

Comment: If you want your controller to handle the request, the only way to then bounce to a new site is to issue a new request, ie a redirect, eg maybe using [CI's `redirect`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html#redirect) or [PHP's `header`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). Presumably you've already tried this but as you haven't shown us any code or explained how `it failed`, nor shown the `triggered errors`, nobody can help much further ... (PS `redirect()` in CI4 does not use URL helper, as shown in the docs).